# Inserting new records into table with row number as id with PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, insert, primary-key

I have a database table, let's call it `Foo`. Foo has an `id` column (which is long), and some data columns, let's call them `Bar1` and `Bar2`

There is a script that used to work before there was an `id` column, that would simply add new stuff into the table like this:

```
INSERT INTO Foo
SELECT OldBar1, SUM(OldBar2)
FROM OldFoo
GROUP BY OldBar1
```

Now, after the `id` has been added, if I have a new, `Foo` table empty initially, then I can do this:

```
INSERT INTO Foo
SELECT row_number() OVER() as id, OldBar1, SUM(OldBar2)
FROM OldFoo
GROUP BY OldBar1;
```

And the data in `Foo` table will have their `id`s equal row numbers.

However, when there is existing data in the `Foo` table and I execute the previous query, I get an exception stating that "Key (id)=(1) already exists".

Obviously, I do not want the row_number to look at the source, the `OldFoo` table, but rather to the new, `Foo` table.

To draw a parallel example in Java, using `HashMap<Integer, Foo>` as the repository:

```
map.put(map.size() + 1, fooObject);
```

Is there a way to achieve this, to generate the ID which will be the same as row number in the target table?

Comment: You want to declare the column to be `serial` so the database handles the auto incrementing.  See the numeric types here:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the tables are generated via JPA, so I'm not sure how to achieve this with entity classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend finding a way to use `serial`.  However, assuming that there are no other `insert` operations occurring on the table, the following should work for you:

```
INSERT INTO Foo
    SELECT (f.maxId + row_number() OVER() )as id, OldBar1, SUM(OldBar2)
    FROM OldFoo CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT MAX(id) as MAX(ID) FROM Foo) f
    GROUP BY OldBar1, f.maxId;
```

A piece of advice: when using `INSERT` always include the column names.  So your query should read something like `INSERT INTO Foo(Id, OldBar)`.  This makes the code easier to maintain and to understand.

Comment: Of course, I was simply using `Foo`a and `Bar`s to hide the real table and column names :D Could you tell me anything about the performace of this way of inserting?

Comment: A question tho: Using this approach the following error occurs: `ERROR: column "f.maxid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.

Comment: It appears that `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) private Long id;` translates into `SERIAL`, which makes my life a lot easier :D Thank you very much, answer accepted :D